# How to fix access denial error when copying an excel file programmatically within a thread in C#

Tags: c#, excel, multithreading, vsto, backgroundworker

I'm writing a program which copies an excel file to another location and removes the sheets except for the visible sheets and saving the copied file. I have used the BackgroundWorker class in order to achieve this.

First, I initialized the Background Worker methods.

```
private void InitializeBackgroundWorker()
        {
            backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            backgroundWorker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker_DoWork);
            backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted);
            backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged);
        }
```

"BackgroundWorker.DoWork()" method is as follows.

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            GenerateReports(worker);

            // Cancel the asynchronous operation.
            if (worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return;
            }

            worker.ReportProgress(100);

            if(backgroundWorker.IsBusy)
            {
                this.backgroundWorker.CancelAsync();
            }
        }
```

The "GenerateReports()" method contains the "ExtractVisibleSheets()" method which extracts the visible sheets, which then calls the "CopyVisibleSheets()" method.

```
private void ExtractVisibleSheets(String originalDirectory, String convertedDirectory)
        {
           //Get the .xlsx files of the original reports and the converted reports
            visibleSheetsOriginal = Directory.GetFiles(originalDirectory, "*.xlsx");
            visibleSheetsConverted = Directory.GetFiles(convertedDirectory, "*.xlsx");

            //Copy the visible sheets to the defined workbooks
            //Sample Reports
            CopyVisibleSheets(originalDirectory, visibleSheetsOriginal, visibleSheetsBasePath);

            //Converted Reports
            CopyVisibleSheets(convertedDirectory, visibleSheetsOriginal, visibleSheetsConvertedPath);                
        }
```

```
private void CopyVisibleSheets(String directory, String[] excelFiles, String path)
        {
            excelApplication = null;
            workbook = null;
            Excel.Worksheet sheet = null;
            String copiedReport = "";

            try
            {
                foreach(String report in excelFiles)
                {
                    copiedReport = path + "\\" + report.Substring(report.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);

                    excelApplication = GetExcelApplication();

                    File.Copy(report, copiedReport);

                    OpenXmlFileProcessor.RemoveCustomProperty(copiedReport, FileProcessor.BaClientVerParam);

                    workbook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(copiedReport);

                    EnableDisableAlertsAndEvents(false);

                    for (int i = workbook.Worksheets.Count; i > 0; i--)
                    {                       
                        sheet = excelApplication.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets[i];
                        if(sheet.Visible != XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible)
                        {
                            sheet.Visible = XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible;
                            sheet.Delete();                            
                        }                                             
                    }

                    workbook.Save();

                    EnableDisableAlertsAndEvents(true);

                    workbook.Close();

                    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
                }                
            }
            finally
            {
                QuitAndReleaseExcelApplication(false);
            }
        }
```

"BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted()" method is given below

```
private void backgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // First, handle the case where an exception was thrown.
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
            }
            else if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                // Next, handle the case where the user cancelled 
                // the operation.
            }
            else
            {
                // Finally, handle the case where the operation 
                // succeeded.                
                MessageBox.Show("Directory Generation Successful!");                    
            }

            EnableControls();
        }
```

But an error occurs during the line "File.Copy(report, copiedReport)" as follows and is fired up from the "BackgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted()" method.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoRd4.png)

Do let me know if someone knows the reason for this error.

Comment: i'll take a stab and say it's because access is denied to the file path...

Comment: I suspect you forgot to use the `directory` variable that you passed in.

Comment: What are the actual values passed to the `File.Copy(report, copiedReport)` method?

Comment: @mjwills it worked fine before I added the threading part and I will try to add a short example.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev value for report is "Sample_1.xlsx" and value for copiedReport is the path combined with the name of the report.i.e "C:\\SampleFolder\\Sample_1_Copy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a rule, the system `C:` drive requires admin privileges for writing. I'd suggest choosing another drive or folder (application data).

Answer (score 0):

```
path + "\\" + report.Substring(report.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1);
try to use double qute "" (report.LastIndexOf('\\') + 1); 

its a type of strings 
try to use path + "//" + report.Substring(report.LastIndexOf("//") + 1);
```

correct me if im wrong :)

Comment: Hi, this isn't related to the format of the path since it worked before I added the threading part :)